# Tortoise-ORM. Displaying External Entities in PyDantic Models

Tags: python, pydantic, tortoise-orm

Faced the problem of displaying external entities in PyDantic models.

I have an entity structure in the database:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = fields.BigIntField(pk=True)
    username = fields.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True)

class Message(models.Model):
    id = fields.BigIntField(pk=True)
    date = fields.DatetimeField()
    user: fields.ForeignKeyRelation["User"] = fields.ForeignKeyField("models.User", on_delete=fields.CASCADE)
    text = fields.TextField()
```

I created models through pydantic_model_creator:

```
UserRp = pydantic_model_creator(User, name="UserRp")
MessageRp = pydantic_model_creator(Message, name="MessageRp")
```

I'm trying to call a request through the construction:

```
await MessageRp.from_queryset(Message.filter(user=user_id).order_by("-date"))
```

Returns all fields except user. Even if you supplement the string with the prefetch_related("user") method.

Tell me what could be the problem. Adding include to pydantic_model_creator failed

Answer (score 0):

You should call tortoise intialisation before creating pydantic models:

https://tortoise.github.io/examples/pydantic.html#relations-early-init